# Redirect non www. to www. url into light speeds based webstore

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect example.com to www.example.com.

I tried from `.htacess` with right 301 redirect code but doesn't work.

Also without www url redirect to other domain that haven't redirect from `.htacess`.

Comment: Please post the 301 redirect code you tried in your `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this .hataccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure your .htaccess only one "RewriteEngine On".
So, you can put

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To below RewriteEngine On